# Print multiple files field links, descriptions and file extensions in Twig

Tags: 8, theming, entities

I have a content type with a field `field_file_attachment` that allows uploading multiple files with txt, pdf, gif and img extensions.

I would like to get links, descriptions and extensions of all these files printed in my Twig file `node--page--full.html.twig`.

Is this possible? Should I create a preprocess function for page?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do something like this,

```
{% for file in node.field_file['#items'].entity %}
  {{ file.uri.value }}
  {{ file.name.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt work for me.

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: Ah I didn’t see that you posted and answer yourself

Comment: I think the best answer is a combination of both, loop over the field in the node `{% for file_item in node.field_file %}` and get the file name `{{ file_item.entity.name.value }}` and other file values.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will be helpful for other,
I use:

```
{% for file in content.field_file['#items'] %}
  {{ devel_dump(file.entity.name.value)}}
{% endfor %}
```

It gives me acces to all values from file field.

Answer (score 0):

> You need to pass your file or image field `uri` value with
>   `file_url()` function, Read the [**Drupal Docs**](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/functions-in-twig-templates),
>   Then you will have field's exact value, **not** rendered

```
{{ file_url(node.field_policy_pdf.entity.uri.value) }} - if it has limited (1) value.
```

**Else you need to use twig** `{% for %} loop`